# What might "S/A-V-O" and "A/S-V-O" mean?

Tags: syntax, terminology, linguistic-typology, word-order

In looking through [Google Books's preview of *A Grammar of Lao* by N. J. Enfield](http://books.google.com.au/books?id=cePDX9kIAFAC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_vpt_reviews#v=onepage&q=a/s%20v%20o&f=false), I came across these two terms, which I'm assuming are equivalent to one another (possibly one is even a typo) and some kind of variant of **"SVO"**, representing the word order subject-object verb:

- **S/A-V-O**

  > By unmarked I mean that the speakers report an impression that the S/A-V-O pattern is somehow basic in status. A consultant will likely supply the S/A-V-O pattern when asked to compose sentences of the variety *The farmer killed the duckling*, ...
- **A/S-V-O**

  > With this in mind, consider the Lao A/S-V-O constituent order pattern, perhaps the closest to a pragmatically unmarked pattern:
  >
  > Departures from the A/S-V-O pattern are common. Movement, for example, may see a subject argument in a post-final position ...

Comment: I stand corrected btw., that was most unfortunate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Abbreviations list of that book is viewable (if you search for "abbreviations"), and says "A = agent-like argument of transitive clause" and "S = single argument of intransitive clause".

Comment: Now why didn't I think of that? (-:

Comment: But what's the difference between S/A and A/S? Is it just scribal variation, or is there a significance in the ordering?